# skip first state and direct to sepecified state (Animator untiy3d)

Tags: animation, unity-game-engine, animator

Very first, sorry for my english. :-( In my game, when enemies spawn (when first all enemies are died) then they came in walking animation but I want, when they spawn, they came in scary animation state because fighting mode is enabled, I am enbling bool variables but nothing happening, even I use this.anim.Play(); but no use. Here is my code and my animator picture.

```
    public void start_firing()
{

    firsttime_look_towards_player_bool = true;
    firing_mode_activated = true;
    stop_next_pos = true;
    this.anim.SetBool ("look_here_there",false);
    this.anim.SetBool ("idle_look",false);

    this.anim.SetBool ("scared_run", true); // not working

    if (is_firing_mode_already_on) 
    {
        get_destination_position_script ();
        is_firing_mode_already_on = false;
        firsttime_look_towards_player_bool = true;
        this.anim.Play ("Scared run (no gun)2",0, 0f); //here I want to start scary state
        dest_positions_script.get_random_position_for_firing (this,recieve_pos_firing);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: In the transition between walk and scared run do you have Has exit time checked? What is the condition on this transition?

Comment: solved, some other problem, not a problem of states ,